# Why does awk -F work for most letters, but not for the letter "t"?

Tags: awk, macos

```
 July 2022      mac os Monterey V12.1 
   awk --version 20200816
   GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21)
```

Why does `awk -F` work for most letters, but NOT for the letter `t`?
I have the solution, but I would like to understand why awk fails for the letter `t`.

```bash
# Count 'e's
% echo "tweeter" | awk -F "e" '{print NF-1}'
3

# Count 'r's
% echo "tweeter" | awk -F "r" '{print NF-1}'
1

# (Attempt to) count 't's
% echo "tweeter" | awk -F "t" '{print NF-1}'
0   <=== ????

# Use gsub()
% echo "tweeter" | awk '{print gsub(/t/, "")}'
2
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Because:

> Normally, any number of blanks separate fields.  In order to set the
> field separator to a single blank, use the -F option with a value of
> `[ ]`.  **If   a field separator of `t` is specified, awk treats it as if
> `\t` had been specified and uses <TAB> as the field separator.**  In order
> to use a literal `t` as the field separator, use the -F option with a
> value of `[t]`.

That's from the [FreeBSD awk man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=awk&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+13.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html), and the utilities that come with macOS are usually some old FreeBSD versions or such.

```
$ printf 'foo\tbar\n' | awk -F t '{print NF-1}'
1
$ echo total | awk -F '[t]' '{print NF-1}'
2
```

In a way, that seems like a useful shorthand for files with tab-separated values, but what with other letters taken as-is, it's confusing. It only works like that with `-F`, using `-v FS=t` doesn't do it.

The feature is non-POSIX, as [POSIX says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/awk.html) that `-F x` is the same as `-v FS=x`. Most other awks I tested treated `t` as the the literal letter (some versions of gawk, mawk and Busybox).

The version of awk that e.g. Debian has in the [`original-awk` package](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/original-awk) ("One True AWK" or "BWK awk" presumably from Brian W. Kernighan's initials) does support it, though, and at least [Wikipedia seems to indicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Versions_and_implementations) that would be the same software FreeBSD uses. This one appears to be based on the version described in the 1988 book "The AWK Programming Language", but I'm not an expert on awk lineages and don't know if it has evolved significantly since then. That one [is on github](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk), but the documentation there doesn't seem to describe the feature. The [special case can be seen in the code](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk/blob/master/main.c#L89) (where it's described as "a wart" in a comment).

[You can get the same behaviour with GNU awk in BWK-awk compatibility mode, though.](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Command-Line-Field-Separator.html):

> As a special case, in compatibility mode (see section Command-Line Options), if the argument to -F is ‘t’, then FS is set to the TAB character. If you type ‘-F\t’ at the shell, without any quotes, the ‘\’ gets deleted, so awk figures that you really want your fields to be separated with TABs and not ‘t’s.

Comment: I wonder if Mr Kernighan was accommodating users who didn't quote the value: `awk -F \t ...` and if sh and csh handled that differently.

Comment: @glennjackman, the GNU documentation that Ed linked to there actually mentions just that. Both sh and csh drop the backslash there.

Comment: @QuartzCristal and Ed, it might not even matter, at least [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Versions_and_implementations) the awk that FreeBSD uses _is_ BWK awk / nawk. The version messages look the same between the macOS one and the Debian "original-awk" one. (And I'm not going to dig deeper. The one I have that came with macOS is an older version though)

Comment: FWIW, in rc `-F\t` remains as is as backslash is not a quoting operator there. In `es` or `fish`, `-F\t` becomes `-F<TAB>`.

Comment: The interpretation of `"t"` (it happens to be quoted, as it should, in the OP) as TAB seems like a misfeature of BSD's awk.

Comment: @QuartzCristal, it's just like that in the awk that Debian has in the `original-awk` package. Or the one available at https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk. ([this function](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk/blob/master/main.c#L89)) It doesn't matter if you quote the `t` there, `-F t`, `-F \t` and `-F "t"` all give the same result in the shell: the two arguments `-F` and `t`.

Comment: Yes @ilkkachu . Both suffer of the same illness IMO. But if you have the (correct) habit of quoting the FS parameter as in `-F "\t"` (as it should be done) the shell will not change the value. Then it becomes shocking (as an odd surprise) that `-F "t"` gets interpreted as a TAB. And `nawk` (which some people supposedly claim that is the same binary as bwk) doesn´t do that (at least in Debian (nor Fedora, I believe)).

Comment: It's not described in POSIX; POSIX says that `-F sepstring` is equivalent to `-v FS=sepstring`, and no special handling for `t` is described of `FS`.

Answer (score -4):

the *absolutely* safest way, regardless of shell/env combo, is to use a square-cage and double-backslash for the tab

> ```
> FS='[t]'         # for just lowercase "t"
> ```

> ```
> FS='[\\411]'     # for the tab "\t"
> ```

with the doubling of `\\` even though it's inside single quotes, shall any environment get too smart and try stripping one of them off, `awk` will still it as the underlying byte of tab itself.

if youre **really** paranoid about it, then do

> ```
> FS='[\534\564]'  # for the tab "\t"
> ```